# Node Backend Application Database Connection Objectorientated

Tags: javascript, typescript, sqlite, class, module

I am working on a backend application with node using typescript / javascript. My backend is using a sqlite database. I structured my project so that there is one file that contains all the database logic.

I could either write a module that will be required by all modules that or I could write a class which connects to the database in the constructor.

For me it seems a little bit weird to pack all database logic in a module that is not an object. What is the best practice in this case and why? (I know this might be a stupid question but I'm just a hobbyist)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my case I make the connection to the database before running the server. In pseudocode:

```
connectorDB.connect( path, config, () => {
    server.listen( port )
})
```

It will depend on how important the database connection is in the operation of your app.